# How to find the bounds of integration for a tetrahedron

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image: Picture of questions]

I'm looking to find the bounds of integration for this solid. I know that it ends up being 0 to 2-x-y for the z bounds, 0 to 2-x for the y bounds, and 0 to 2 for the x bounds, but I'm not sure how to get there. I graphed the tetrahedron on paper and the equations make sense, could anyone explain how to find the bounds?

Comment: Try solving the problem in two dimensions first - integrate over the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(0,2)$. Then generalize.

Comment: Can you find the equations of the planes that coincide with the boundary of $T$?